# Grab SQL variables that changes in query in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

How do I get variable @Test that was changed in query?

```
        const string query = @"SET @Test = 2;";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test", 1);
            var r = command.ExecuteReader();
            // command.Parameters["@Test"].Value == 1
            // r hasn't any variables                
        }
```

ADDED:
I've solve this problem withoute creating stored procedure

```
        const string query = @"SET @Test = 2;";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            SqlParameter par = command.Parameters.Add("@Test", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
            par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // par.Value now contain 2
        }
```

Both ansvers help!

Comment: If you are changing the @Test parameter why would you want to know if it has changed?

Comment: I EXTRACT part of code, to make it clear. I have a complex query!

Comment: Question is in - How do I get changed variable @Test! It must be equal 2.

Comment: check this link which shows how to read from an output parameter. [Output Parameter](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/CallStoredProcedurewithinputandoutputparameters.htm)

Comment: You should proably attach a bit more of your complex query because this question makes very little sense as is.

Comment: Don't need all understoodable)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in your stored procedure the parameter needs to be marked as `OUTPUT`

```
CREATE PROC MyQuery
    @Test INT OUTPUT
AS
SET @Test = 2
```

Then, when constructing the c# code, instead of using `AddWithValue`, be more explicit in your creation of a `SqlParameter`, namely marking it as Input/Output.

```
var command = new SqlCommand("MyQuery", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var param = command.CreateParameter();
param.Name = "@Test";
param.Type = DbType.Int;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
param.Value = 1;
```

Now once you execute your command:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Could also be ExecuteReader, if you have a resultset too!
```

You can read the value of param, which should have changed to 2

```
if(param.Value == 2)
{ Console.WriteLine("WooHoo"); }
```